# How can I dynamically reference a variable key name in a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with the name *data* containing objects like so:

```
[{"timeslot":"6am-7am","Monday":5},{"timeslot":"7am-8am","Monday":0},{"timeslot":"8am-9am","Monday":10}]
```

Each object contains two key-value pairs. I need to create two new arrays:

- an array, *timeslot*s, containing each value associated with the "timeslot" key
- an array, *numUsers*, containing each integer value associated with the "Monday" key

Here is my Javascript:

```
var timeslots = [];
var numUsers = [];
var keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
var today = keys[1]; 


for(var i in data) {
    timeslots.push(data[i].timeslot);
    numUsers.push(data[i].today);
}
```

The first line of the for loop works, and returns the following *timeslots* array:

```
["6am-7am", "7am-8am", "8am-9am"]
```

The second line, however, returns an array of undefined elements.

My problem is, the second key value of the objects in the *data* array varies. Each object will contain the same day of the week, but this day can be any one of "Monday" through "Sunday".

How can I reference it dynamically?

Answer (score 3):

You can access object value using *square brackets notation* in the same way as you use it with `i`:

```
numUsers.push(data[i][today]);
```

**N.B.** However, your code has several very important problems that will eventually bring you errors. One of the most visible is that you rely on the order of the object properties and retrieve an array of keys with `Object.keys`, setting the second key as the value of `today` variable. Your mistake is that in different systems and browsers the code like `Object.keys(obj)[1]` may return different results, as *object properties in JavaScript don't have order*. Also, you shouldn't use `for .. in` statement to iterate arrays, instead utilise simple `for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++)` loop. And finally, don't forget, that `data` array may contain zero items, so your code `data[0]` will raise an error. I would suggest you to reconsider the business logic of your application and probably to rewrite it to make it more reliable.

Comment: Wow - that was simpler than I thought. Time for bed.

Comment: This solution will not work if the day is going to vary, unless you set `today` *inside* the loop.

Comment: @ChrisG Your solution won't work as well. Please read the note I've added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need this:

```
  numUsers.push(data[i][Object.keys(data[i])[1]]);
```

Comment: Why do you think that the OP wants to use anything different apart from the second property of the first item of `data`? His code kinda makes sense and your suggestion brakes the initial idea.

Comment: Because he specifically says so in the last paragraph of his question: "My problem is [...]"

Comment: From what I see, he meant that the `data` array may have times for `"Tuesday"`, `"Wednesday"`, etc, but one `data` can have times only for a single day of week. That's why he introduces `today = keys[1]` before the actual loop.

Comment: I don't see where he says that, I'm reading it differently. And I guess you're confused because there are actually two separate problems with the OP's code: not only do you need to read the key dynamically inside the loop, you also have to use `[today]` as opposed to `.today` for it to work. You're fixated on the latter problem, but the varying 2nd key is still important.

Comment: Apparently I'm not confused. He has just updated his question. Now it states clearly: *Each object will contain the same day of the week, but this day can be any one of "Monday" through "Sunday"*. And of course the code contains much more problems on a deeper look: I have provided all details in the **N.B.** section of my answer.

Comment: Yeah... I saw it, too.

Comment: Apologies for not being more explicit about this point. Thank you both for your contributions.